Which game is shown in the "Virtual Boy Pro for Nintendo Switch" announcement trailer?
The recent announcement trailer for the Virtual Boy Pro for Nintendo Switch showcased a game running on the console. It looked like a Legend of Zelda title, with the player character riding a horse across the landscape.

My guess is that it's either The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild or The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom. I searched for "Legend of Zelda" and "horse" in YouTube videos to reach this conclusion, but I can't say for certain since I neither own a Nintendo Switch nor have I played these games.
Can anyone confirm which game is shown in the "Virtual Boy Pro for Nintendo Switch" trailer?




No need to clarify it's a parody, never trust an announcement trailer made on 1st April lol

It's definitely The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom.

If you look at the minimap, there are 3 coordinates in the lower side that are not present in Breath of the Wild, since the game extends also on different layers.
Also the D-pad quick menu is different, iirc the "apple" on up is not present in Breath of the Wild, since you don't have to access your fusing materials.
